# Magento: Default parameter values for widgets

Tags: php, magento, widget

I defined a widget in the `widget.xml` and several paramters, for example

```
<parameters>
      <headline translate="label">
          <visible>1</visible>
          <label>Display Amount</label>
          <type>text</type>
          <required>1</required>
      </dheadline>
</parameters>
```

How can I define a default value for such a parameter to be shown in the configuration field in the backend when the user creates the widget.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `<value>` :

```
<parameters>
      <headline translate="label">
          <visible>1</visible>
          <label>Display Amount</label>
          <type>text</type>
          <required>1</required>
          <value>default value</value>
      </dheadline>
</parameters>
```